# Reduce overload on pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-performance

I have a requirement to do matching of few attributes one by one. I'm looking to avoid multiple select statements. Below is the example.

```
    Table1
    Col1|Price|Brand|size
    -----------------------
    A|10$|BRAND1|SIZE1
    B|10$|BRAND1|SIZE1
    C|30$|BRAND2|SIZE2
    D|40$|BRAND2|SIZE4


    Table2
    Col1|Col2|Col3
    --------------
    B|XYZ|PQR
    C|ZZZ|YYY


    Table3
    Col1|COL2|COL3|LIKECOL1|Price|brand|size
    -----------------------------------------
    B|XYZ|PQR|A|10$|BRAND1|SIZE1
    C|ZZZ|YYY|D|NULL|BRAND2|NULL
```

In table3, I need to insert data from table2 by checking below conditions.

1. Find a match for record in table2, if Brand and size, Price match
2. If no match found, then try just Brand, Size
3. still no match found, try brand only

In the above example, for the first record in table2, found match with all the 3 attributes and so inserted into table3 and second record, record 'D' is matching but only 'Brand'.

All I can think of is writing 3 different insert statements like below into an oracle pl/sql block.

```
 insert into table3 
   select from tab2 
    where all 3 attributes are matching;

 insert into table3 
   select from tab2 
    where brand and price are matching 
      and not exists in table3 (not exists is to avoid 
                                inserting the same record which was already 
                                inserted with all 3 attributes matched);

 insert into table3 
   select from tab2 
    where Brand is matching and not exists in table3;
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way to achieve it in any better way avoiding multiple times selecting from table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for `OUTER APPLY`.

`OUTER APPLY` is a type of lateral join that allows you join on dynamic views that refer to tables appearing earlier in your `FROM` clause.  With that ability, you can define a dynamic view that finds all the matches, sorts them by the pecking order you've specified, and then use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` to only include the 1st one in the results.

Using `OUTER APPLY` means that if there is no match, you will still get the table B record -- just with all the match columns `null`.  If you don't want that, you can change `OUTER APPLY` to `CROSS APPLY`.

Here is a working example (with step by step comments), shamelessly stealing the table creation scripts from Michael Piankov's answer:

```
create table Table1 (Col1,Price,Brand,size1)
as select 'A','10','BRAND1','SIZE1' from dual union all
   select 'B','10','BRAND1','SIZE1' from dual union all
   select 'C','30','BRAND2','SIZE2' from dual union all
   select 'D','40','BRAND2','SIZE4'from dual 

create table Table2(Col1,Col2,Col3)
as select 'B','XYZ','PQR' from dual union all 
   select'C','ZZZ','YYY' from dual;

-- INSERT INTO table3
SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3,
t1.col1 likecol1, 
decode(t1.price,t1_template.price,t1_template.price, null) price,
decode(t1.brand,t1_template.brand,t1_template.brand, null) brand,
decode(t1.size1,t1_template.size1,t1_template.size1, null) size1
FROM 
-- Start with table2
table2 t2
-- Get the row from table1 matching on col1... this is our search template
inner join table1 t1_template on
t1_template.col1 = t2.col1
-- Get the best match from table1 for our search 
-- template, excluding the search template itself
outer apply ( 
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
WHERE 1=1
-- Exclude search template itself
and t1.col1 != t2.col1
-- All matches include BRAND
and t1.brand = t1_template.brand
-- order by match strength based on price and size
order by case when t1.price = t1_template.price and t1.size1 = t1_template.size1 THEN 1
when t1.size1 = t1_template.size1 THEN 2
else 3 END
-- Only get the best match for each row in T2
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) t1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know about outer apply. Now after understanding this, my question is, can't the same be achieved with normal outer join? What's the difference between both? What happens if I write like referring to table1 twice and like below?

 `SELECT <> 
    FROM table1 t1
         INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1_template
            ON (t1.price = t1_template.price AND t1.size1 = t1_template.size1)
   WHERE t1.col1 != t1_template.col1 AND t1.brand = t1_template.brand
ORDER BY brand, price NULLS LAST, size1 NULLS LAST`

Comment: The `OUTER APPLY` is required to sort the matches for each search and only give you the strongest match, according to your requirements.

Comment: Based on this example to which you provided guidance, I developed code for my requirement with more tables and more match conditions. I was under assumption that case clause in order by is same as normal order by and will sort just column position by the number. But while testing I understood that's not the case. So can you throw some light on usage of numbers in case clause in order by.

Comment: Yes -- each `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` is a match condition.  E.g., `WHEN` price and size match then "1".  `WHEN` just the size matches then 2.  There is nothing special about the numbers -- it's just that 1 sorts before 2, so the rows with stronger matches sort first and, since you `FETCH` only the 1st row, you'll get the strongest match only out from the `OUTER APPLY`.  Nothing special about "1" and "2" -- they are NOT column position identifiers.  They are just literal numbers.  I could have used "A" and "B".

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. And what if I need to do a lateral join of `CROSS` apply with 2 different tables. Should I have 2 different `CROSS APPLY` clauses or can I have both in just one?  Assume along with doing this match of brand or other attributes from one table, if I need to do a match of an area or region etc from another table, how should I do it? Can you please help me out on understanding.

Comment: The `CROSS APPLY` should list all the matches for a given template and sort those matches strongest first.  If you have to go to multiple tables to derive the matches, they should be joined inside of the `CROSS APPLY` and accounted for in the `ORDER BY` clause inside the `CROSS APPLY`.  It sounds like you shouldn't create a second `CROSS APPLY`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Hello Matthew, Thanks a lot for all your responses on this so far and now I am back with another question on this. :)
Based on the example you provided, I have taken it forward with multiple tables and multiple matches and with `outer apply`. Now there is a new requirement of finding closest match instead of exact match. Referring to the same example above, say, for the brand, the **exact** match need to found, but for the price, **closest** match is required. I am out of ideas on how to handle this in `order by case` clause. Can you help me with some idea here? @Matthew McPeak

Comment: The `OUTER APPLY` is all about selecting any row you deem to be a "match" and then sorting them in the preferred order, and then fetching only the most preferred.  If I understand your new requirement correctly, order your `OUTER APPLY` by something like `ABS(t1.price-t1_template.price) ASC` to get the closest match by price.  If I haven't understood correctly, perhaps you should post a fresh question.

Comment: I added new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030624/cross-apply-with-closest-match, Can you please have a look @Matthew McPeak

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not clear what do you mean when say match. What is you expectation if there is more then one match? 
Should it be only first matching or it will generate all available pairs?

Regarding you question how to avoid multiple inserts there is more then one way:

1. You could use multitable insert with `INSERT first` and condition.
2. You could join table1 to self and get all pairs and filter results in where condition
3. You could use analytical function
4. I suppose there is another ways. But why you would like to avoid 3 simple inserts. Its easy to read and maintain. And may be

There is example with analytical function next:

```
create table Table1 (Col1,Price,Brand,size1)
as select 'A','10','BRAND1','SIZE1' from dual union all
   select 'B','10','BRAND1','SIZE1' from dual union all
   select 'C','30','BRAND2','SIZE2' from dual union all
   select 'D','40','BRAND2','SIZE4'from dual 

create table Table2(Col1,Col2,Col3)
as select 'B','XYZ','PQR' from dual union all 
   select'C','ZZZ','YYY' from dual

with s as (
select Col1,Price,Brand,size1, 
        count(*) over(partition by Price,Brand,size1 ) as match3, 
        count(*) over(partition by Price,Brand ) as match2,
        count(*) over(partition by Brand ) as match1,
        lead(Col1) over(partition by Price,Brand,size1 order by Col1) as like3, 
        lead(Col1) over(partition by Price,Brand order by Col1) as like2,
        lead(Col1) over(partition by Brand order by Col1) as like1,
        lag(Col1) over(partition by Price,Brand,size1 order by Col1) as like_desc3, 
        lag(Col1) over(partition by Price,Brand order by Col1) as like_desc2,
        lag(Col1) over(partition by Brand order by Col1) as like_desc1
from Table1 t )
select t.Col1,t.Col2,t.Col3, coalesce(s.like3, like_desc3, s.like1, like_desc1, s.like1, like_desc1),
    case when  match3 > 1 then size1 end as size1,
    case when  match1 > 1 then Brand end as Brand,
    case when  match2 > 1 then Price end as Price
        from table2 t
         left join s on s.Col1 = t.Col1 

COL1    COL2    COL3    LIKE_COL    SIZE1   BRAND   PRICE
B   XYZ PQR A   SIZE1   BRAND1  10
C   ZZZ YYY D    -  BRAND2   -
```