# Cross apply with closest match

Tags: oracle, plsql, cross-apply

I have a requirement to do matching of few attributes one by one. I'm looking to avoid multiple select statements. Below is the example.

```
Table1
Col1|Price|Brand|size|Color
-----------------------
A|10$|BRAND1|10|Red
B|25$|BRAND1|20|Red
C|30$|BRAND1|15|Red
D|40$|BRAND2|25|Blue
E|40$|BRAND2|30|Blue
F|35$|BRAND3|31|Blue


Table2
Col1|Col2|Col3
--------------
B|XYZ|PQR
F|ZZZ|YYY


Table3
Col1|COL2|COL3|LIKECOL1|ClosestPrice|brand|size|Color
------------------------------------------------
B|XYZ|PQR|C|25|BRAND1|15|Red
F|ZZZ|YYY|E|40|NULL|NULL|Blue
```

In table3, I need to insert data from table2 by checking below conditions.

Find a match for record in table2, if Brand and Color match and size and Price have the closest match.
If no match found, then try just Color(exact match), Size and price closest match
If still, no match found, try color exact match and price closest match.

In the above example, for the first record 'B' in table2, found a match as C and so inserted into table3 and second record F, record 'E' is matching but only Color and exact match.

Based on some previous posts, I can use cross apply and get the conditions of exact match included, but can anyone help me to include closest match logic too within this?

Comment: Hi Sandeep.  Can you elaborate on what is meant by "Brand and Color match"? To what are they being compared?

Comment: Hi Alex, Match should be found for the records in col1 of table2 say 'B' in table2.
Example - table2 has 'B' for which attributes of 'B' are compared against all records in table1. Hope this clarifies.